# Js #urls doesn't trigger the function on the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to execute a function on a url change mysite.com/#url , for some reason when I click on a link for the first time it doesn't execute the code, 2nd and more times it works as expected , here is the code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.JsLink', function(event) {
    // hashUrl gets the url after the #
    var hashUrl = window.location.hash.substr(1);
   // if hashUrl is not empty should execute the function
    if (hashUrl) {getResultsByUrl(hashUrl);}
});
```

links :

```
<li class="li-menu JsLink"> <a  href="#sale" >For Sale</a> </li>
<li class="li-menu JsLink"> <a  href="#rent" >For Lease</a> </li>
```

there is no problems with the function coz I tried it with `if (hashUrl) {alert('hello');}`
and it also executes only after 2nd click , Thank You

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click', '.JsLink a'`

Comment: please check your current page url, it may already have #sale or #rent. If yes, please remove it and click again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the  click event is fired before the URL is actually changed.

You should read the `href` property of the anchor itself:

```
var hashUrl = $(this).attr("href").substr(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler runs *before* the URL gets changed by the anchor tag. So the first time through, you don't see any hash in the URL. The second time through, there is a hash (from the first click).

You may want to use `$(window).bind('hashchange', function (event) { ... });` instead.

Comment: I dont think this resolves the issue actually, although you got the problem right.

Comment: @robertotomás Why do you say that?

Comment: You know, I was wrong. You _do_ get the same behavior though, if you first come to the page without any anchor, and your first click loads the anchor.

Comment: Are you saying the first hash change isn't triggering your `hashchange` event handler? If so, you may want to start your own question and provide a way to reproduce the issue.

Comment: oh no, I got it solved, I just manually add an initial blank anchor to the location on document ready. From looking at it, and I was just doing this, `hashchange` _never_ fires when there is no anchor in the URL pre-change.

Comment: @robertotomás I'm pretty sure that's not true. I just tested and verified.

Comment: I guess that's good to know. Im not interested in digging up what was in the way though, it is working just fine setting the location onReady